# Individual IDs for listeners using a custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I'm rather new to the Android SDK, and I recently started developping a small application. The application centers around a menu, which is implemented using a custom `ListView`. I used [this guide as a reference in order to build my model classes and my adapter](http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-titles-icons-counter/). The author also published the code he used on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/hmkcode/Android/tree/master/android-pro-listview/src/com/hmkcode/android). My result is rather close from the original one, the screen below is from the author's blog post:

[image]

I successfully set up my menu, and now comes the time when I need to connect every item of the list to the listener so that I can handle clicks. In order to keep it simple, I had my activity implement `OnClickListener`:

```
public class MenuActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I was also able to connect my menu items to this method through my menu items' XML files:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_layout">
```

Now, whenver I click on one of my list items, I enter the `onClick` method. However, once I'm there, I can't find a way to distinguish an item from other. As you can see, I applied my click event to their layouts, so that it is triggered when I click an item in it (my texts).

However, since all my items share the same XML layout, they also seem to share the same ID: `@id/menu_item_layout`. Because of that, I can't do the usual...

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.myId: /* ... */ break;
        case R.id.myId2: /* ... */ break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Given this "custom list" implementation, is there a way I could distinguish a click on *Menu item1* from a click on *Menu item 2*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `OnClickListener` will not function as you expect with a `ListView`. However, the `ListActivity` class provides the `onListItemClick()` method, that is implemented as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{

}
```

The `position` parameter will hold the index in the underlying data list corresponding to the item clicked.

Comment: If `onClickListener` wouldn't be one of the options then it would be impossible to have only a button clickable inside list item not the whole list item view. It would be also impossible to have two buttons inside the same list item. But it is possible... However your solution is also correct.

Comment: @michal.z Maybe I should've phrased that better, but I didn't say an `OnClickListener` doesn't work at all; just that it doesn't work as I'm interpreting how the OP is thinking it does. Also, no one said anything about multiple, clickable child Views, and, given that the ListView is being used as a menu, that shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Ok, so simply misunderstanding occured. :) I just wanted to clarify that by my comment.

Comment: Since my question was related to a `ListActivity` feature, I will accept this answer, thank you! Tags were a nice idea as well, however they end up making things a lot more complicated in my code...

Comment: @michal.z Understood. :-) Nothing wrong with having more information!

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Cool. If I have misunderstood something, or if I'm not fully realizing the scope of your question, please lemme know. Happy to clear anything up. Of course, there are always several different ways to do things; this just seemed the simplest with your given description and code.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `View` for a list item in your `ListAdapter` you can set tag on that view using `View#setTag`. Put there something which can distinguish one list item from another i.e. position in adapter. Then use `View.getTag` to get this unique identifier in `onClick` listener.

Answer (score 0):

What i think is, there are two ways to do this:

First:

Add clicklistener to the view inside the getview method, that way you would also be having the position(remember to initialize a final int to the position inside getView and use that int inside your clickListener)

Second:(not guaranteed if it will work)

Add a tag to every textView inside getView and store the position in that textView. ex:

```
textView.setTag(new Integer(int position));
```

and then fetch that position in the onClick method of yours